# Unresolved identifier when trying to create modal view with .sheet in XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have been following this [tutorial](https://blckbirds.com/post/core-data-and-swiftui/) to familiarise myself with ios development. For some reason, I seem to be unable to resolve the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'LeadDetails'" in Line 31 of my code.

```
LeadDetails().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext)
```

I am sure it must be a rather simple mistake somewhere, but I cannot figure it out for the life of it, and would be glad if somebody could point me in the right direction.

I have included a picture of the project structure below.
Thanks a lot in advance!

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BzEq.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    @State var showLeadDetails = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                Text("Sample Lead")
            }
        .navigationBarTitle("My Leads")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            self.showLeadDetails = true
        }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32, alignment: .center)
            }))
            .sheet(isPresented: $showLeadDetails) {
             LeadDetails().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        return ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext,context)

    }
}
```

Edit1: The code for LeadDetails is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LeadDetails: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show the code for LeadDetails(). If you don't have the code, then this is your problem.

Comment: where is LeadDetails() defined?

Comment: @workingdog the code for LeadDetails() is currently dummy code only. I will add it above

Comment: @ingAlioth You can see that I am very much a beginner here. I thought this would be done via the .environment... declaration. Could you give me hint on how to probably define it?

Comment: I copied your code above, it compiles and run without any problems for me. I'm using Xcode 11.5, macos 10.15.5, target ios 13.5 and mac catalyst.

Comment: yes @K4m1, exact code is working for me without any error. Checking with Xcode 11.1

Comment: Does defining `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext` in the struct fix the problem? 
```swift
struct LeadDetails: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```